# Get selected elements of a multiple selection dropdwon box

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, drop-down-menu, multipleselection

How do I get the list of the selected options in multiple selection dropdown. I am using this jQuery plugin here: [searchable-option-list](https://github.com/pbauerochse/searchable-option-list)

I have tried this but does not give the select it. Only the first value gets logged in the db. I want to save the the collection of all the selected values.
This is the jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $('#companytype').searchableOptionList();
                });

                var items = [];
                $('#companytype option:selected').each(function(){ items.push($(this).val()); });
                var result = items.join(', ');
                console.log(result);
            </script>
```

This is multiple select:

```
<select name="companytype" id="companytype" class="mid first-input-div" multiple="multiple">
                                <optgroup label="UPSTREAM">
                                    <option value="Peter">Peter Griffin</option>
                                    <option value="Lois">Lois Griffin</option>
                                    <option value="Chris">Chris Griffin</option>
                                    <option value="Meg">Meg Griffin</option>
                                    <option value="Stewie">Stewie Griffin</option>
                                </optgroup>

                                <optgroup label="MID-STREAM">
                                    <option value="Cleveland">Cleveland Brown</option>    
                                    <option value="Joe">Joe Swanson</option>    
                                    <option value="Quagmire">Glenn Quagmire</option>    
                                </optgroup>

                                <optgroup label="DOWNSTREAM">
                                    <option value="Oil and transportation">Oil and transportation</option>    
                                    <option value="Bunkering">Bunkering</option>    
                                    <option value="Brokering">Brokering</option>    
                                </optgroup>    
                            </select>
```

I am using Laravel, this is the code for insertion:

```
public function store(CompanyRequest $companyRequest)
    {
       $company = new Company;

       if($companyRequest->isMethod('post')){

       $company->user_id        = Auth::user()->id;
       $company->companyname    = $companyRequest->companyname;
       $company->companytype    = $companyRequest->companytype;

       $company->save();
       return redirect()->route('companyindex')->with('message', 'Your question has been posted.');
       }else{
            return redirect('company-create')->withErrors($companyRequest)->withInput();
        }
    }
```

[image: MySQL DB record]

Comment: could you add some, html and your db insertion try outs?

Comment: Thanks. I have fleshed it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you need to change `name="companytype"` to `name="companytype[]"`. convert the element to array, as the selection here is multiple. and retrieve the same in your server script, `request in array format` implode some string needle, and then insert that into database.

**i believe, your PHP change should be something like this. *(after changing to array)***

```
$company->companytype    = $companyRequest->companytype;
```

change the above statement to

```
$company->companytype    = implode(",",$companyRequest->companytype);
```

this should help you.

Comment: Appreciate your support, when I did this, it gives the error as sited: `Cannot use [] for reading`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Your wise instructive professional advice  saved my day. Thanks. God bless. I only remove the array symbols.  `$company->companytype    = implode(",",$companyRequest->companytype);`

Comment: you are always welcome, @kehinde, i have no idea, how laravel supports an array element request, thought as a normal request does, use of `[]` may solve the issue. if you know the request on array element, please update it to community so that it could be useful. Thanks :)